# Golf a PSK31 modulator

Tags: code-golf, encoding, audio

Given a string of ASCII text as input, encode it in [BPSK31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSK31) using [Varicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicode). You may either output an audio file in any common format, or play the audio over the device speakers. You may output at any sample rate and with any carrier frequency between 500 Hz and 2500 Hz. The sample rate and carrier frequency must be consistent.

### Specifications

#### Varicode

Varicode is a character encoding in which characters are given variable-length binary codes, none of which contain the bit sequence `00`; this is because `00` is a separator between consecutive codes. This use of [Fibonacci coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_coding) enables more commonly-used letters to be given shorter codes in a simple form of compression. All ASCII characters, including both printable and control characters, are supported by Varicode.

#### Control characters

| Varicode | Oct | Dec | Hex | Abbr | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1010101011 | 000 | 0 | 00 | NUL | Null character |
| 1011011011 | 001 | 1 | 01 | SOH | Start of Header |
| 1011101101 | 002 | 2 | 02 | STX | Start of Text |
| 1101110111 | 003 | 3 | 03 | ETX | End of Text |
| 1011101011 | 004 | 4 | 04 | EOT | End of Transmission |
| 1101011111 | 005 | 5 | 05 | ENQ | Enquiry |
| 1011101111 | 006 | 6 | 06 | ACK | Acknowledgment |
| 1011111101 | 007 | 7 | 07 | BEL | Bell |
| 1011111111 | 010 | 8 | 08 | BS | Backspace |
| 11101111 | 011 | 9 | 09 | HT | Horizontal Tab |
| 11101 | 012 | 10 | 0A | LF | Line feed |
| 1101101111 | 013 | 11 | 0B | VT | Vertical Tab |
| 1011011101 | 014 | 12 | 0C | FF | Form feed |
| 11111 | 015 | 13 | 0D | CR | Carriage return |
| 1101110101 | 016 | 14 | 0E | SO | Shift Out |
| 1110101011 | 017 | 15 | 0F | SI | Shift In |
| 1011110111 | 020 | 16 | 10 | DLE | Data Link Escape |
| 1011110101 | 021 | 17 | 11 | DC1 | Device Control 1 (XON) |
| 1110101101 | 022 | 18 | 12 | DC2 | Device Control 2 |
| 1110101111 | 023 | 19 | 13 | DC3 | Device Control 3 (XOFF) |
| 1101011011 | 024 | 20 | 14 | DC4 | Device Control 4 |
| 1101101011 | 025 | 21 | 15 | NAK | Negative Acknowledgement |
| 1101101101 | 026 | 22 | 16 | SYN | Synchronous Idle |
| 1101010111 | 027 | 23 | 17 | ETB | End of Trans. Block |
| 1101111011 | 030 | 24 | 18 | CAN | Cancel |
| 1101111101 | 031 | 25 | 19 | EM | End of Medium |
| 1110110111 | 032 | 26 | 1A | SUB | Substitute |
| 1101010101 | 033 | 27 | 1B | ESC | Escape |
| 1101011101 | 034 | 28 | 1C | FS | File Separator |
| 1110111011 | 035 | 29 | 1D | GS | Group Separator |
| 1011111011 | 036 | 30 | 1E | RS | Record Separator |
| 1101111111 | 037 | 31 | 1F | US | Unit Separator |
| 1110110101 | 177 | 127 | 7F | DEL | Delete |

#### Printable characters

| Varicode | Oct | Dec | Hex | Glyph |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 040 | 32 | 20 | SP |
| 111111111 | 041 | 33 | 21 | ! |
| 101011111 | 042 | 34 | 22 | " |
| 111110101 | 043 | 35 | 23 | # |
| 111011011 | 044 | 36 | 24 | $ |
| 1011010101 | 045 | 37 | 25 | % |
| 1010111011 | 046 | 38 | 26 | & |
| 101111111 | 047 | 39 | 27 | ' |
| 11111011 | 050 | 40 | 28 | ( |
| 11110111 | 051 | 41 | 29 | ) |
| 101101111 | 052 | 42 | 2A | * |
| 111011111 | 053 | 43 | 2B | + |
| 1110101 | 054 | 44 | 2C | , |
| 110101 | 055 | 45 | 2D | - |
| 1010111 | 056 | 46 | 2E | . |
| 110101111 | 057 | 47 | 2F | / |
| 10110111 | 060 | 48 | 30 | 0 |
| 10111101 | 061 | 49 | 31 | 1 |
| 11101101 | 062 | 50 | 32 | 2 |
| 11111111 | 063 | 51 | 33 | 3 |
| 101110111 | 064 | 52 | 34 | 4 |
| 101011011 | 065 | 53 | 35 | 5 |
| 101101011 | 066 | 54 | 36 | 6 |
| 110101101 | 067 | 55 | 37 | 7 |
| 110101011 | 070 | 56 | 38 | 8 |
| 110110111 | 071 | 57 | 39 | 9 |
| 11110101 | 072 | 58 | 3A | : |
| 110111101 | 073 | 59 | 3B | ; |
| 111101101 | 074 | 60 | 3C | < |
| 1010101 | 075 | 61 | 3D | = |
| 111010111 | 076 | 62 | 3E | > |
| 1010101111 | 077 | 63 | 3F | ? |
| 1010111101 | 100 | 64 | 40 | @ |
| 1111101 | 101 | 65 | 41 | A |
| 11101011 | 102 | 66 | 42 | B |
| 10101101 | 103 | 67 | 43 | C |
| 10110101 | 104 | 68 | 44 | D |
| 1110111 | 105 | 69 | 45 | E |
| 11011011 | 106 | 70 | 46 | F |
| 11111101 | 107 | 71 | 47 | G |
| 101010101 | 110 | 72 | 48 | H |
| 1111111 | 111 | 73 | 49 | I |
| 111111101 | 112 | 74 | 4A | J |
| 101111101 | 113 | 75 | 4B | K |
| 11010111 | 114 | 76 | 4C | L |
| 10111011 | 115 | 77 | 4D | M |
| 11011101 | 116 | 78 | 4E | N |
| 10101011 | 117 | 79 | 4F | O |
| 11010101 | 120 | 80 | 50 | P |
| 111011101 | 121 | 81 | 51 | Q |
| 10101111 | 122 | 82 | 52 | R |
| 1101111 | 123 | 83 | 53 | S |
| 1101101 | 124 | 84 | 54 | T |
| 101010111 | 125 | 85 | 55 | U |
| 110110101 | 126 | 86 | 56 | V |
| 101011101 | 127 | 87 | 57 | W |
| 101110101 | 130 | 88 | 58 | X |
| 101111011 | 131 | 89 | 59 | Y |
| 1010101101 | 132 | 90 | 5A | Z |
| 111110111 | 133 | 91 | 5B | [ |
| 111101111 | 134 | 92 | 5C | \ |
| 111111011 | 135 | 93 | 5D | ] |
| 1010111111 | 136 | 94 | 5E | ^ |
| 101101101 | 137 | 95 | 5F | _ |
| 1011011111 | 140 | 96 | 60 | ' |
| 1011 | 141 | 97 | 61 | a |
| 1011111 | 142 | 98 | 62 | b |
| 101111 | 143 | 99 | 63 | c |
| 101101 | 144 | 100 | 64 | d |
| 11 | 145 | 101 | 65 | e |
| 111101 | 146 | 102 | 66 | f |
| 1011011 | 147 | 103 | 67 | g |
| 101011 | 150 | 104 | 68 | h |
| 1101 | 151 | 105 | 69 | i |
| 111101011 | 152 | 106 | 6A | j |
| 10111111 | 153 | 107 | 6B | k |
| 11011 | 154 | 108 | 6C | l |
| 111011 | 155 | 109 | 6D | m |
| 1111 | 156 | 110 | 6E | n |
| 111 | 157 | 111 | 6F | o |
| 111111 | 160 | 112 | 70 | p |
| 110111111 | 161 | 113 | 71 | q |
| 10101 | 162 | 114 | 72 | r |
| 10111 | 163 | 115 | 73 | s |
| 101 | 164 | 116 | 74 | t |
| 110111 | 165 | 117 | 75 | u |
| 1111011 | 166 | 118 | 76 | v |
| 1101011 | 167 | 119 | 77 | w |
| 11011111 | 170 | 120 | 78 | x |
| 1011101 | 171 | 121 | 79 | y |
| 111010101 | 172 | 122 | 7A | z |
| 1010110111 | 173 | 123 | 7B | { |
| 110111011 | 174 | 124 | 7C | | |
| 1010110101 | 175 | 125 | 7D | } |
| 1011010111 | 176 | 126 | 7E | ~ |

#### PSK31

BPSK31, the most common variant of PSK31, modulates the phase of a constant carrier wave to transmit the information. Every 32 ms, the phase of the carrier is either changed by 180°, representing a binary 1, or left unchanged, representing a binary zero. The signal is filtered with a [raised-cosine filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised-cosine_filter) to reduce interference.

### Test cases

#### Varicode

| Input | Varicode |
| --- | --- |
| `Code Golf` | `10101101001110010110100110010011111101001110011011111101` |
| `CQ` | `1010110100111011101` |

#### PSK31

Unfortunately, there's really no way to give test cases for the modulation itself, because the output doesn't have to precisely match a particular value. However, for testing, you can use [Fldigi](http://www.w1hkj.com/) to decode your results.